# RISCV vectored trap handling: ambiguity when CAUSE = 0

Tags: exception, interrupt, riscv

I got a question about vectored trap handling.
Long story short:

- Traps can be either sync exceptions or async interrupts
- In vectored mode the vector table is accessed like this:
- Exceptions: PC = BASE (fixed entry point)
- IRQs: PC = BASE+4*CAUSE (vectored)
  Problem is that of course if CAUSE = 0 there is ambiguity.
  Since CAUSE = 0 hold true for user-software interrupts, the [manuale (sec 3.1.7)](https://riscv.org/specifications/privileged-isa) says:

> When  vectored  interrupts  are  enabled,  interrupt  cause  0,  which  corresponds  to  user-mode  soft-
> ware  interrupts,  are  vectored  to  the  same  location  as  synchronous  exceptions.   This  ambiguity
> does  not  arise  in  practice,  since  user-mode  software  interrupts  are  either  disabled  or  delegated
> to a less-privileged mode

Now, I understand that in M-mode, U-interrupts are disabled. But what if an exception arrives while I'm in U-mode? Am I missing something like that exceptions are handled in M-mode only?
Also, I don't understand why there is no ambiguity if the handler is exactly the same. Shouldn't software test if the trap occured because of an exception or the user-software interrupt?